# Clojure Unix time stamp for previous day

Tags: unix, datetime, clojure

```
(defn todaydate [& props]
(let [
tester(str "")
tester (let [today (Date.)]
   (.getTime today))
```

The piece of code above returns a unix timestamp for the current day. I want to be able to use the `tester` to get a unix timestamp for the day previous to this.

The `clj-time` library is not available to me for using to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use a [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), add negative one days, and then use `getTimeInMillis` divided by 1000 to get the timestamp.

The following would give you the unix timestamp for midnight yesterday.

```
(let [yesterday (doto (GregorianCalendar. (TimeZone/getTimeZone "UTC"))
                  (.set Calendar/HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                  (.set Calendar/MINUTE 0)
                  (.set Calendar/SECOND 0)
                  (.set Calendar/MILLISECOND 0)
                  (.add Calendar/DAY_OF_YEAR -1))]
  (/ (.getTimeInMillis yesterday) 1000))
```

**Note:** Be careful about the timezone you use.

Also, if you just need something quick, you could just subtract the number of seconds in a day from the value you have.